# has_many through association with adding information to middle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, has-many-through

I have two models join by a middle model

```
class Integration < ActiveBase
  has_many :integration_records
  has_many :records, through: :intragration_records
end

class IntegrationRecords < ActiveBase
 belongs_to :integrations
 belongs_to :records
end

class Records < ActiveBase
  has_many :integration_records
  has_many :integrations, through: :intragration_records
end
```

Now, IntegrationRecords has a JSON data column that is nil by default.

I want to create an integration, with its respective record and add data to the data column on integration_records

I was thinking of something like this but didn't work:

```
 Integration.create!(whatever_data).integration_records.create(data: {}).records.create(whatever)
```

This fails... I noticed it creates a record automatically for

```
 Integration.create!(whatever_data).integration_records.create(data: {})
```

So next thought is:

```
 Integration.create!(whatever_data).integration_records.create(data: {}).records.update(whatever)
```

Didn't work. Help someone!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try step by step.
1- create the Integration
2- create the integration_record
3- create the record

```
integration = Integration.create!(whatever_data)
integration_record = integration.integration_records.create!(data: {})
record = integration_record.records.create!(data: {})
```

You can add a transaction to be sure that `integration` will be record only if `integration_record` and `record` are created.

Answer (score 0):

This is literally what the << operator is for. Your current code isn't working because you're integration_records is returning an empty array, and you can't run "create" on an empty array. :)

So one option:

```
class Integration < ActiveBase
  has_many :integration_records
  has_many :records, through: :intragration_records
end

class IntegrationRecords < ActiveBase
 belongs_to :integrations
 belongs_to :records
end

class Records < ActiveBase
  has_many :integration_records
  has_many :integrations, through: :intragration_records
end

i = Integration.create!(data)
i.records << Record.create!(data)
```

That should do it.

Comment: Now i get this error: `No association found for name `records'. Has it been defined yet?`

Comment: Whoop yeah that won't work, accepted_nested_attributes_for only works from parent -> child models. Moment!

Comment: any luck with that? see my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23438421/has-many-through-middle-model-not-creating