# has_many through middle model not creating, but creating duplicate of one model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through

I have two models join by a middle model

```
class Integration < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :integration_records
 has_many :records, through: :integration_records
end

class IntegrationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :integration
 belongs_to :record
end

class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :integration_records
 has_many :integrations, through: :integration_records
end



  i = Integration.create(whatever)
  i.records.create(whatever)
  => (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (8.7ms)  INSERT INTO "records" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Sat, 03 May 2014 00:31:02 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Sat, 03 May 2014 00:31:02 UTC +00:00]]
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "records" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Sat, 03 May 2014 00:31:06 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Sat, 03 May 2014 00:31:06 UTC +00:00]]
 (0.4ms)  COMMIT

  i.records 
  => [one record]

  Record.all.count
  => 2

  i.integration_records
  => #<IntegrationRecord id: nil, integration_id: 1, record_id: 2 >
```

Notice id is `nil`

```
  IntegrationRecord.all
  => #<ActiveRecord::Relation []> 

  IntegrationRecord.create
  => #<IntegrationRecord id: nil, integration_id: nil, record_id: nil>
```

Notice id is `nil`

```
  Record.create.integrations.create
  => (0.1ms)  BEGIN
     SQL (8.7ms)  INSERT INTO "integrations" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Sat, 03 May 2014 00:31:02 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Sat, 03 May 2014 00:31:02 UTC +00:00]]
     SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "records" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Sat, 03 May 2014 00:31:06 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Sat, 03 May 2014 00:31:06 UTC +00:00]]
     (0.4ms)  COMMIT
```

Not sure why this is happening, in the case of `i.records.create(whatever)` it should output:

```
      SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "records" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Sat, 03 May 2014 00:31:06 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Sat, 03 May 2014 00:31:06 UTC +00:00]]
     (0.4ms)  COMMIT
      INSERT INTO "integration_records" ("created_at", "data", "integration_id", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Sat, 03 May 2014 15:57:05 UTC +00:00], ["data", {}], ["integration_id", 5], ["updated_at", Sat, 03 May 2014 15:57:05 UTC +00:00]]
```

I should note that for some reason, when I create a new app in rails 4.0.4, I still had this problem. But when I change the names of the models and specifically `Record` model, it works perfectly fine. So when I changed it to `Recordrow` no problem at all.

Comment: You have few typos, can you please double check your question and fix them first.

Comment: @vee done! Take a look now

Comment: I still see several typos.  Sorry about that.  The `through` reference is spelt wrong, I'm not sure what `ActiveBase` does so I'll leave that judgement to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your current association setup, all you need to do is, just follow these simple instructions step by step

1. **Create an Integration record**

   ```
   ## this will create an "integration" record in "integrations" table
   integration = Integration.create(whatever)
   ```
2. **Create an associated  `Record` record**

   ```
   ## this will create an associated "record" entry in "records" table
   ## PLUS this will also created an associated record in "integration_records" table
   integration.records.create(whatever)
   ```
3. **View the associated records and associated integration_records**

   ```
   ## Display all the "records" entries associated to this particular integration
   integration.records

   ## Display all the "integration_records" entries associated to this particular integration
   integration.integration_records
   ```

**UPDATE**

`i.records.create(whatever)` was creating 2 records, found out that the issue was with the name `records` of the table. Once changed everything works fine. It looks like `records` is reserved word.

Also, OP found this link which states **[records is reserved](http://reservedwords.herokuapp.com/words/records?page=6&q%5Bword_or_notes_cont%5D=)**

Comment: I would like to see you follow each of the steps as suggested in my answer and share the output for each step. Add the results in your question. This will help me to pin point your issue.

Comment: Update my question again.

Comment: Thanks. I don't see output of ` i = Integration.create(whatever)`, the very first one.

Comment: Let's debug this on chat, join me at http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48530/ror